# Add custom class to body tag | TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to add custom class to body tag to each page what I want, for example:  for Tag pages class `<body class="tagClass">`, for main page class `<body class="mainClass">` and for detailed pages `<body class="classDetailed">`.

I`m using TYPO3 7.6.0 andi have installed on it Blog extention, this blog extention  pages i want this classes.

some examples  or link would be very helpful for me.

By the way this post i saw [TYPO3 Adding a class to the body tag on a specifc page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236782/typo3-adding-a-class-to-the-body-tag-on-a-specifc-page) but it isn`t what i want

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#bodytagadd

Comment: Thank you but i`m new  in Typoscript so this link is unusable  for me , i need some examples  to understand how it`s work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are using 'page' as TypoScript ContentObject PAGE and have two different page trees, which starts with page id 10 and 20, you can use following TypoScript setup/configuration:

```
[PIDinRootline=10]
    page.bodyTagAdd = class="foo"
[end]

[PIDinRootline=20]
    page.bodyTagAdd = class="bar"
[end]
```

Comment: But how i can determine in which page i`m and set specific class name  for this page ?

Comment: You can also place the directions (without the bracketed conditions) directly in the page tree as typoscript "templates". They will then cascade nicely through the page tree until they're overridden by another statement.